# Mass-checking TCP port host

Tags: php, tcp

I`m work on site, something like game-monitor.com but for a small indie game

I need to poll a ton of tcp ports (just simple "check if port is open then disconnect") continually, how should I do this? What is best practice for this?

I tried @fsockopen on every pageload for live, and it just makes page take $timeout * numberofhosts to load.

How should I do this? I have a database col already named online (1/0) - should I run a cron to update? What happens if no one visits page? Should I do something like embed "cron.php" as an image and make it run if it hasn't run in the last x minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have access to PHP scripting, do the host check in a cron job. Just pick a few hosts at once to make the script go faster and run it multiple times instead.

If you have no visitors for a long time you can stop the polling, but I really don't see why you should do that. Checking open ports is not that expensive (on your own server; I don't think your hosting provider will like it if you're on shared hosting).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use PHP but some language that supports threads (e.g. Python) and run it from time to time with a (real) cronjob. Then spawn a bunch of threads to you can parallelize the checking.

Comment: Any suggestion on this ? I have shared hosting only, permitted Rails and PHP . I also have not experiences in Python so I might have issues learning just for one task.. thx for fast reply btw..

Comment: Shared hosting providers most likely do not want you to open lots of sockets at all.

Comment: Shared hosting providers most likely block most ports in their own firewall.

Comment: Also check if you can use `nmap` (a linux command that does port scanning pretty well).

Comment: @Carlos: That's pretty much like telling the shared hosting provider "please cancel my contract".